Confidence and prediction intervals for polynomial regression in a non-normally distributed dataset?
I'm applying polynomial regression (Python—polyfit) to a dataset and have been asked to include confidence intervals, and as this is well outside my field, I have concerns. Mainly that this may not be the best method to display variation for this given dataset. The data are measurements at set normal stresses, with the regression based on the shear stiffness results - these results are not normally distributed, and it's a polynomial regression fit (though displayed linearly). The intent was for a formula to estimate shear stiffness - I initially included R2 and p-value, but I've been asked to include confidence intervals to show variation too.
I guess my questions are - is the attached an appropriate and meaningful method to show variation? Is the confidence interval of the prediction meaningful given the dataset (polynomial regression, non-normally distributed), or should I investigate bootstrapping given the distribution? Or is there a better method of showing variation in the data altogether?

z = np.polyfit(maxNormal_np, np.log10(chr_stiff_cleaned), 1)    
p = np.poly1d(z)    
predictions = p(maxNormal_np)    
ax2.plot(maxNormal, 10 ** predictions, label='Fit', zorder=4)    
ax2.scatter(maxNormal_np, chr_stiff, marker='o', color="green", 
label='Data')  


Does the picture you attached show your results or is this a random image?

The picture is the actual results, sorry, should've made that clearer.

The formula in the legend seems to show a non-linear formula (instead of a quadratic one)? How did you make a linear plot from a quadratic fit?

The y-axis is log - so there's a bit of conversion to/from. See below for some code snippets:
z = np.polyfit(maxNormal_np, np.log10(chr_stiff_cleaned), 1)   
p = np.poly1d(z)
predictions = p(maxNormal_np)   

ax2.plot(maxNormal, 10 ** predictions, label='Fit', zorder=4)
ax2.scatter(maxNormal_np, chr_stiff, marker='o', color="green", label='Data')


I see, you transformed your data using log10 before fitting the model and then fit a polyfit with degree 1... so it is a linear fit? Was there a reason for the log10 transformation? There is no normal distributional assumption for the data in a linear model. Also, your fit does not look very good, points in the interval from 4 to 12 look like they follow a different trend compared to the edges.

@user2974951 The log10 transformation was solely for visual purposes, it's the only way I've seen this data plotted before (it would've been far easier not to transform to/from). And yes, 1 degree was linear, I don't know why it didn't occur to me to increase this as 3 degrees provides a far better fit given the edges as you say, likely I was happy with the 0.75 and didn't think to try and improve. How does changing it to 3 degrees impact the use of prediction/confidence intervals? Is it worth my time including them? That was one of my concerns, the lack of normal distribution in the data.
